# Minecraft framerate is lower in Ubuntu. Why?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ubuntu, framerate

Recently, I moved over to Ubuntu for various performance reasons, but I've seen a major drop in my Minecraft framerate. Usually I get 100-250 in Windows, but Ubuntu is struggling to keep me at 60.

I have my graphics card drivers (Optimus) installed properly, and Optifine is working with the same settings as it was in Windows.

Are there any solutions to restore my old Windows framerate?

Comment: which versions of windows and ubuntu?

Comment: @Aequitas Windows 8/10 vs Ubuntuy 14.04.5

Comment: probably the opneGL stuff is accelerated on linux so it's syncing to your monitor refresh rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found that my issue was that `bumbleebee` and `primus` was limiting my graphics card capability.

To resolve this issue, I followed the below steps:

1. Remove Bumblebee by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
   ```
2. Install `nvidia-prime` by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
   ```
3. Reboot the system
4. Open the NVIDIA control panel and ensure that it's set to "NVIDIA".
5. Check all files in `/etc/modprobe.d` to ensure that my NVIDIA driver is not blacklisted.
6. Reboot yet again

After doing this, I'm back to my old framerate and no more screen tearing.

Comment: Yes, but you will use a lot more energy. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, Bumblebee is installed by default. It allows you to choose between your integrated Intel chipset, or your Nvidia graphic card, in order to **save energy**. By default, everything runs on the chipset.

To launch Minecraft (or any software) using the Nvidia card, you have to use the command `primusrun minecraft`. You can also modify the *Desktop Entry*, which should be a file named "Minecraft.Desktop" in `/usr/share/applications`, so that when you click on the Minecraft icon in your launcher it automatically uses `primusrun`.

Comment: I was using Bumblebee, but it was the source of all of my problems. Unless there's a way to make it perform better, it'll still be a problem.

Comment: Were you actually using `primusrun` ? Also, I'm not sure if the latest nvidia drivers are installed by defautl.

Comment: I was using `primusrun` and `optirun`, neither of which gave good results.

Comment: Ok. Probably bad configuration, but that's a pain to fix and quite different from computer to computer.